# Does malloc without corresponding free always produce a memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

Does `malloc` without corresponding `free` always produce a memory leak, or are there situations when it doesn't?

Comment: The memory stays allocated, whether you need it or not, until it's freed.  But you don't need a 1:1 correspondence between them in your source code, as long as everything you allocate gets freed (eg. the `malloc` and `free` could be in different functions, or one `free` line could execute several times to free several blocks allocated in different parts of your code, etc.).  Also, when the program exits anything still left allocated is usually freed anyway.

Comment: Basically, the number of calls at runtime to `malloc`, etc., should match the number of calls to `free`, but not necessarily the number of occurences in the source.

Comment: `realloc(malloc(1000),0)` may free allocated memory without a `free()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you define "memory leak". If you define it as having any outstanding objects with allocated storage duration at the time of program exit, then yes, it's a leak. This is what tools like valgrind report. However, it's not a useful definition at all.

My definition of memory leak is roughly an unbounded increase in total memory consumption of the program over its lifetime despite having a bounded working set. For example, if I always have at most 10 tabs open in my browser, to the same 10 sites, but memory usage keeps increasing unboundedly, that's a memory leak. On the other hand, a program that allocates a buffer to load a whole file into memory, loads the file, prints it in reverse, then exits without freeing the memory does not have a memory leak.

One particular important case where a `malloc` without `free` is not only not-a-leak but absolutely necessary (for general code that can't make assumptions about the whole program it's running in) is any use of runtime-allocated constant tables whose generation is controlled by `call_once`. No matter how late you tried to free such tables, it would be possible for code (in another thread, or an `atexit` handler, etc.)  to attempt to access it after free, and `call_once` type interfaces intentionally do not provide any way to synchronize any access except first call (this is how they avoid introducing unwanted acquire barriers/synchronization cost at every read).

Note that the concept of "working set" here is somewhat subjective and highly load-bearing. Often memory leaks are a matter of the software still considering something part of its working set when the user no longer considers it so.

Comment: You're missing the fact that (code from) small programs is often practically packaged and reused as a callable function within another program.     In such a case, having allocated storage that is not deallocated at program termination of the small program provides a demonstration of cause of the growing memory consumption in a larger program.    In such cases, the two definitions you give are equivalent - just applicable to the same code in different contexts.

Comment: @Peter: I didn't "miss" it; rather we have different opinions on the matter. In particular, "code" in isolation doesn't have or not have memory leaks; *programs* do. Of course it's possible for code to be such that it's impossible to use it in any practical way without introducing memory leaks into the program, but real-world cases are usually not that simple.

Comment: @Peter: I've added text with a specific example of why the ability to allocate and never free is important.

Answer (score 2):

A ***memory leak*** is a situation where a program allocates memory, does not free it when it is no longer in use, and loses track of its address (the value of the pointer returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`).

Since the pointer is lost, the memory can no longer be freed and will stay attached to the program until it exits.

If the program exits, all memory associated with it is reclaimed by the operating system (except for rare circumstances beyond the scope of this question), so the *memory leak* has no consequences.

If the program executes for a long time, potentially until the system is shut down, unused blocks of memory attached to the program cannot be used for other purposes. If the amount of memory thus wasted is small, again no consequences are expected.

Conversely, if the program keeps allocating more memory and not free it, the system will run out of memory for the program to use and either return `NULL` for an allocation request or become unstable as it uses virtual memory to honor the requests at the expense of other programs and at the cost of lengthy swapping operations to storage devices or other compression techniques. At some point the system may kill processes at random to try and recover usable memory.

Such *memory leaks* are problematic and must be avoided. They are especially problematic in library functions that may be used in programs that run for extended sessions, such as web browsers, email readers, file managers, media players, program managers...

Unlike other programming languages, C does not have an embedded garbage collector that could determine which allocated blocks of memory are still in use, so it is the programmer's responsibility to keep track of all allocated blocks and free them as soon as possible.  Advanced tools such as **valgrind** can be used to verify if all allocated blocks have been freed upon program exit. Although it is not necessary to free the memory at exit, it is good programming practice and a good way to determine if all allocated memory blocks have been accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

The answer might depend on the implementation of `malloc`, but generally there are two cases where `malloc` is expected to not produce a memory leak:

1. when you pass it 0 as the size parameter, some implementations will just return `NULL` and not allocate anything, while others will return an unique pointer and even though this counts as zero bytes allocated you will leak about 64 bytes anyway in bookkeeping records.
2. When Out Of Memory happens. Check out the global variable `errno` to have specific values, normally `ENOMEM` to see if it failed. In such cases `malloc`returns `NULL` as well.

Comment: 3. when you define memory leak to exclude benign memory allocations intentionally kept till the end of the program. +1

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not require a memory leak at all. So per se, there is no situation that will guarantee a memory leak.

On the other hand the standard does not require a memory leak to not happen in the scenario you mention either.

In most situations, all allocated memory will be freed when the program exits. But there may be exceptions on some systems, especially embedded ones. If this is vital to your program, you should not rely on it.

Comment: It seems you are defining "memory leak" as "memory still allocated by a process that no longer exists". Just noting this because that's not one I've seen before.